# newRange As Range is not recognized in ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(newRange).Value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to assign values from one spreadsheet to this one and it works when I give the range of cells in the macro (like Range("A3:J4")), but not when I try to manually select the destination cells.

So this works:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
'Select and Open workbook

OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("DATA,*.txt")
If OpenFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenFileName)

    'Get data EXAMPLE    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Range("A3:J4").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A3:J4").Value
    wb.Close
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
'Select and Open workbook

OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("DATA,*.txt")
If OpenFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenFileName)

    Dim newRange As Range
    Set newRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 9))

    'Get data EXAMPLE  
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Range(newRange).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A3:J4").Value
    wb.Close
```

Comment: Have you tried adding .Range to ActiveCell?

Answer (score 0):

In the second instance, you are treating `newRange` as if it was a string var of the [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx). You can use it directly.

```
'this assumes that 'newRange' is on Sheets(5)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).newRange.Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A3").Resize(newRange.Rows.Count, newRange.Columns.Count).Value
'alternative use as the cell range address
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Range(newRange.address).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A3").Resize(newRange.Rows.Count, newRange.Columns.Count).Value
```

When using direct value transfer, the ranges have to be the same size.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, thank you for your help. With your suggestion, should I change something in this part of the code?

Dim newRange As Range
    Set newRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 9))

Because if I just exchange the lines for what you suggested it is not working unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `Selection`-property?
Try

```
Set newRange = Selection
```

For more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx

Afterwards reference the newRange.address on the other sheet:

```
Worksheets("TargetSheetName").Range(newRange.address)
```

Comment: Hi Rik, thank you for your help. With your suggestion I managed to select my own range as destination for the values to be copied. Do you know if there is a way to add a certain number of rows to this selection? Even better would be if I could select one cell and that the code knows to increase this selection by x rows and x columns. Thanks again!

Comment: I just realized that I should have placed this code more up in the macro, that made it work with your suggestion, thanks very much!

`Dim newRange As Range
    Set newRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 9))`

Comment: Dear B. de Wolf, that is indeed the part that should be replaced. If you wish to resize your selection (e.g. make it bigger compared to the selection) you can use `Range.Resize()` - See [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193274.aspx)